# Firebase_messaging onResume and onLaunch callbacks are not called in flutter

Tags: flutter, callback, firebase-cloud-messaging

**What I want to do**

I want to navigate to specific screen when the user taps on fcm notification in the notification tray.

**My Code**

I've followed the exact same instructions as mentioned on pub.dev for version 6.0.9.

Here is my implementation:

```dart
_fcm.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('@onMessage: $message');
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('@onResume: $message');
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen()));
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('@onLaunch: $message');
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen()));
        });
```

**Plugin version:** firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9

I've also added these configurations:

**app/build.gradle:**

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'`

**project/build.gradle:**

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:'1.3.50'"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

**Expected output**

When the users taps notification in the backgroud, onResume or onLaunch callback is called and he's redirected to the mentioned screen.

**Actual output**

onResume and onLaunch are not called while onMessage is called properly when the app is in foreground.

Comment: are you sure you followed the steps in https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging?
its just from steps 1 - 4 and its good already

Comment: Yup, I checked once again. Followed the exact same steps. 
onMessage callback works perfectly but it sucks with onResume and onLaunch as it doesn't generate any exception as well.

Comment: can you please remove the Navigator.push?

Comment: I think the probllem is on navigation

Comment: I removed the Navigator as well and just left the message but still no result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the notification payload misses "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" then
onclick and onresume functions  will not be called.But onmessage function will work perfectly.
Try with this  payload  in terminal

```
DATA='{"notification": {"body": "this is a body","title": "this is a title"}, "priority": "high", "data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",  "route":"booking", "bookingId":"319", "userType":"host", "status": "done"}, "to": "<FCM TOKEN>"}'
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "$DATA" -H "Authorization: key=<FCM SERVER KEY>"
```

FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK is must to  call  onresume and onmessage

Comment: how to do it in firebase console? add key data  value {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" or  directly add "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"?

Comment: it should be added as  on additional option custom data  as "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

Comment: thank you for ios remove the 5th step mentioned in doc , it's started working

Answer (score 0):

```
Complete guide for notification handling:

In payload = [
    notification: {
       title: _title //Title of the notification
       data: {
             message: msg,
             click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
             // Any message that you want to send in notification
             screen: 'chat'
       }
    }
]



//Inside app you configure as:

 FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

 handleMessaging() {
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    // showNotification(
    //     message['notification']['title'], message['notification']['body']);
    print("onMessage: $message");

    print('Data is: '+ message['data']['screen'].toString());

  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print("Called onLaunch");
    print(msg);
    print('Data is: '+ msg['data']['screen'].toString());

    if(msg['data']['screen'].toString() == 'chat app') {
      return //Navigate to chat app
    }
    return null;
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    //(App in background)
    // From Notification bar when user click notification we get this event.
    // on this event navigate to a particular page.
    print(msg);

    // // Assuming you will create classes to handle JSON data. :)
    // Notification ns = Notification(title: msg['title'], body: msg['body']);
   
    return null;
  },
   onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
   // (App in foreground)
  // on this event add new message in notification collection and hightlight the count on bell icon.
   // Add notificaion add in local storage and show in a list.
   // updataNotification(msg);
   print(msg);
   },
 );
}
```